# Array of string from the console

Tags: java, console, bufferedreader, arrays

I have a task:
"Send integers n [1 .. 10] from command line. Enter n rows to the Console, find the shortest and the longest line. Print the results and line length."

My idea is: Create array of strings and copy every line from `BufferedReader` to the array `data[i]`. Sample of my code:

```
String[] data = new String[n];
int j=0;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please, enter " + i + " string: ");
    String line = in.readLine();
    for (int j=0; j<=data.length;j++){
      data[j] = line;
      j++;  
    } ///:~

    System.out.println("Your " + i + " string : " + data[j] + "String len: " + line.length());
} ///:~
```

But I could not find the way how to fill elements of array `data[i]` with new line from console.
Can you please give me a small hint?

Comment: Do *not* create the BufferedReader inside the loop. Besides the fact that you are creating *n* Reader where you only need one you are loosing the content the previous BufferedReader might have buffered each time you create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

To fill `data`, just replace the inner for-loop with a simple assignment using index `i-1`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please, enter " + i + " string: ");
    String line = in.readLine();
    data[i-1] = line;
    System.out.println("Your " + i + " string : " + data[i-1] + "\nString len: " + line.length());
}
```

I left the loop from `1` to `n` instead of `0` to `n-1` because you're printing `i`.

But if you only want the shortest and longest lines, there's no need to store all the lines, you only need to check the length of the current line against the length of the shortest and longest lines and change them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

the easyst way is

```
data[i-1] = in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for all your Help :)
Here is my example:

```
package taskstring;

import java.io.*;

public class TaskString {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Wrong! please send more numbers to java");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Enjoy! You are going to send " + n + " string(s) to java");
        int maxLen = 0;
        int minLen = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Please, enter " + i + " string: ");
            String line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Your " + i + " string : " + "String len: " + line.length());
            if (maxLen < line.length()) {
                System.out.println("New string is bigger");
                maxLen = line.length();
            } else {
                System.out.println("New string is smaller");
            }


            if (minLen > line.length() || minLen == 0) {
                System.out.println("New string is smaller" + " minLen=" + minLen);
                minLen = line.length();



            } else {
                System.out.println("New string is bigger");
            }

            //return;
        } ///:~
        System.out.println("Max row: " + maxLen + "\nMin row: " + minLen);

    } ///:~
}
```